# Website Deconstruction: Ajax Load Page then Slide In

Tags: ajax, navigation, preloader

I am trying to reproduce this effect but im at not that familiar with javascript to deconstruct these sites on my own. Here are the sites with the effect I am looking for(only the navigation):

http://www.serialcut.com/
http://www.ultranoir.com/
*http://kikk.be/*
*http://www.marcusthomasllc.com/*

- I would like the current page/section to have width:100% so it can be responsive and not show content from other sections.
- When the new page is loading, the loading gif is a nice touch (optional)
- lastly, this is where I think the ajax comes in; if I'm on a page, say *contact* and I click *home* there is only one page slide from *contact* to *home* and not every page in between.

I dont expect anyone to actually break down these sites for me but I would appreciate a push in the right direction. Maybe there are some jQuery plugins or basic concepts I can use. I have searched this site but can only find simple jQuery slidein effects.

Thanks for all your time. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options.

This tutorial: http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

The jQuery scrollTo plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

The Supersized plugin: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Or maybe this tutorial: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

**Just use Google**, there are thousands and thousands of pages with examples and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go using jQuery:

```
    var slideAjax = function(elementid, url, data){
        $('#'+elementid).hide(); //make sure the div we are loading into is hidden
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
        }).done(function(data)){
            $('#'+elementid).html(data).show('slide',{direction: 'right'}, 200); //slide in
        });
    }
```

If you don't mind complexities, you can create a setTimeout to push the loader html in with a time length of like 200 ms.  Then, clear the timer with the done function.  That way, it only shows the loader when the page takes longer that 200ms to load.  This is useful if you can plot your load times on a bell curve.  Typically, a page's load time will sit on an inverted bell curve, where it will either take between 0 and X, or Y and infinity.  If you can map out Y, you can set the loader to start at Y so that it doesn't just show for a split second and cut out.